# Database structures - populating tables via foreign keys and summation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys, ssms

Good afternoon,

I've been trying to brainstorm ways to do this, but I've been unable to think of something solid so far. As a last resort I've decided to ask the brilliant minds on stack overflow on some advice as to how I should do this. Some preface before I get started, I'm using SMSS 18 and Microsoft SQL Server 2017.

First of all, I'll show you the backbone database that I want to achieve with this:

[image: The database structure in question]

1. Should I structure the database another way to achieve what I want to achieve? (A way to log meals with a summation of all the calories, etc.)
2. Is it possible to use foreign keys to populate a column in a foreign table? E.g. using X as primary key, populating Z column(in another table) with Y as a foreign key
3. How do I go about with wrapping this up and using SMSS to create the foreign keys to automatically do this?
4. Is it possible to do summation in MSSQL? I wanted to get the sum of calories in the final meal table so that I can later use that data in tableau to draw comparisons and create representations of that data. Should I let tableau do that or is it possible to do so with MSSQL?

I'm all over the place right now, I know my questions seem daunting, but I'm happy to provide much more information if you're missing anything.

I've got the flow of data planned and designed - but I do not know how exactly to implement this architecture in MSSQL.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand the tables. There is food item, like for a banana having certain calories, fat, etc. Then I see a meal ID. I imagine a meal to consist of several single food items. But I don't see such table in your database. Then, you have calories, fat, etc. in multiple tables. But aren't these just results mostly? Don't store results. If you had a meal table, you could easily write a query to get calories per meal from the food item table for instance. And how does the person come into play?

Comment: The static table represents food items that are pre-logged as well as all their respective macronutrients. What I am trying to achieve is the ability to log multiple food items we have in a meal in  a second table, and to have the macronutrients automatically populated from the data in the static table. In terms of the person, I am trying to assign the food items in a meal to a person whose barcode identifier gets populated from a third table. We want the final table to be a sumation of the macronutrients from the second table that includes a meal identifier created in that table.

Comment: Is there a concern with your existing data model? My only feedback is I would agree with @ThorstenKettner above, regarding your 4th question, unless there is a specific constraint, I would let Tableau do the summation instead of persisting the summation in a separate table. Also, I don't get what are you trying to achieve with the auto-population by foreign key? I assume you would have ETL job that performs the loading, and typically the job is responsible for populating all columns.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Insert images using edit functions. Please ask one question per post.

Comment: This is unclear. What is "what I want to achieve"? Or "populate a column in a foreign table"? "wrapping up" what? "automatically do" what? Etc. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. Why didn't 1 googe answer "Is it possible to do summation in MSSQL?"? Please propose at least some of a SQL design. [mcve] If you don't know enough to that, this is off-topic. [ask]

Comment: Thank you for all the responses and sorry if I dissuaded anyone by my simple questions. I've been pretty nerved due to this daunting project ahead of me. Would using SSIS as a way to implement ETL jobs on the platform be the optimal solution? That is - rather than using primary keys and foreign keys to populate the other databases. I'm planning on going to that route to populating the database.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess this is not really an answer to your question...

I would expect some data model like this:

- ingredient (ingredient_id, ingredient_name, calories, fat, ...)
- meal (meal_id, meal_name)
- meal_ingredient (meal_id, ingredient_id, amount)

Per meal you would then calculate:

```
select mi.meal_id, sum(i.calories * mi.amount), sum(i.fat * mi.amount)
from ingredient
join meal_ingredient mi on mi.ingredient_id = i.ingredient_id
group by mi.meal_id;
```

For persons eating the meals:

- person (person_id, name)
- person_meal (person_id, meal_id, consume_date, consume_amount)

And a query for the persons' daily consumption:

```
select
  pm.person_id, pm.consume_date,
  sum(i.calories * mi.amount * pm.consume_amount),
  sum(i.fat * mi.amount * pm.consume_amount)
from ingredient
join meal_ingredient mi on mi.ingredient_id = i.ingredient_id
join person_meal pm on pm.meal_id, mi.meal_id
group by pm.person_id, pm.consume_date
order by pm.person_id, pm.consume_date;
```

We would not store results reduantly, as we can always write queries to get them from the tables. After all, this is what SQL is about.